# TermSuggestionBuilder Java API in elasticsearch does not return any results

Tags: exception, search, elasticsearch

I have constructed a TermSuggestionBuilder as shown below

```
TermSuggestionBuilder termSuggest = new TermSuggestionBuilder("rule")
            .suggestMode("always") // Always, otherwise the results can vary
            // between requests.
            .text("plabel").field("_instanceName");
```

where rule is the name of the index , plabel is text I am searching for and _instancename is the filed .

The query runs fine from the java code but does not return any results.
The Query consructed looks like this

```
"suggest" : {
"rule" : {
  "text" : "pxretrievreportdata",
  "term" : {
    "field" : "_instanceName",
    "suggest_mode" : "always"
  }
}
```

}

When I try to run the same from the rest client [http://localhost:9200/rule/_suggest] , I get the below exception

```
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 0,
"failed": 1,
"failures": [
{
"index": "rule",
"shard": 0,
"reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[rule][0] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[rule] not supported]; "
}
]
}
```

Where as  running this on rest client give me expected results [http://localhost:9200/rule/_suggest]

```
{
  "my-suggestion" : {
    "text" : "plabel",
    "term" : {
      "field" : "pzInsKey"
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know what mistake am I doing while constructing the TermSuggestionBuilder since the later query when run from rest client does return expected results.

Comment: I am using elasticsearch-1.0.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation in java api is not valid,

I've refactored your code as,

```
SuggestBuilder.SuggestionBuilder suggestBuilder = new TermSuggestionBuilder("my-suggestion")
.text("plabel").field("pzInsKey").suggestMode("always");

SuggestRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSuggest("rule")
.addSuggestion(suggestBuilder);
```

I've not checked the output, but should work.